# Destructuring error depending on order of variables

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I encountered some strange destructuring behavior when reversing a linked list in [this problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list/):

```js
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val, next) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {ListNode} head
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
var reverseList = function(head) {
    let previous = null
    while (head) {

        // Version 1 - works
        [head.next, head, previous] = [previous, head.next, head]

        // Version 2 - doesn't work
        // [previous, head, head.next] = [head, head.next, previous]

        // Version 3 - doesn't work
        // [head, head.next, previous] = [head.next, previous, head]

    }
    return previous
};
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why destructing assignments v2 and v3 don't work while version 1 does. The `head.next` assignment is causing the problem. The error is:

```
Line 16 in solution.js
        [previous, head, head.next] = [head, head.next, previous]
                              ^
TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'next')
```

Can someone explain way version 1 works and versions 2 and 3 do not?

Comment: [Your question does not ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to see the difference if you break up the destructuring into separate assignments.

Version 1 is equivalent to:

```
let temp = [previous, head.next, head]
head.next = temp[0];
head = temp[1];
previous = temp[2];
```

Version 2 is equivalent to:

```
let temp = [head, head.next, previous]
previous = temp[0];
head = temp[1];
head.next = temp[2];
```

And version 3:

```
let temp = [head.next, previous, head]
head = temp[0];
head.next = temp[1];
previous = temp[2];
```

In versions 2 and 3 you're assigning `head.next` *after* you've reassigned `head = head.next`. But you need to change the `next` property of the original `head` node, not the new one.

And if the original `head.next` was `null`, you'll get an error when you try to assign `head.next` after the assignment, because you can't set properties of `null`.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is destructuring the array one by one. Version 2 gives you an error because JavaScript does this:

```js
// What you see:
[previous, head, head.next] = [head, head.next, previous]

// What the compiler sees:
previous = head;
head = head.next; // What is head.next? It hasn't been defined! throw TypeError
head.next = previous; // [JavaScript never gets here since there was an error]
```

Hence why only the first solution works.